Bloc Events not being executed sequentially
I have a piece of code where i need to call two bloc events sequentially the issue is that the first event is fired and api is called but the second is not being called , i tried to debug my code and i came to the conclusion that if i call both events from different blocs , they both get fired but if from the same bloc .. only the first gets fired , any help would be appreciate guys . Thank you

This is my code ( check initState , calling two events from same bloc )


 class _FurniturePageState extends State<FurniturePage> {
  String userImage = "";
  final List<String> _titles = ["Lamp","Chair","Table","Sofa","Bed"];
  final List<String> _images = [
    "assets/images/lamp.png",
    "assets/images/chair.png",
    "assets/images/table.png",
    "assets/images/sofa.png",
    "assets/images/bed.png"
  ];
  late int selectedCategory = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<ShopBloc>(context).add(GetUserDataEvent());
    BlocProvider.of<ShopBloc>(context).add(GetFurnitureEvent("Lamp"));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<ShopBloc,ShopBlocState>(
        listener: (context,state){
           if(state is GetUserDataState){
              setState(() {
                 userImage =  state.userModel.userImage!;
              });
              StorageHelper.saveInfo(state.userModel.name!, state.userModel.email!, state.userModel.phone!);
           }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(child:  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(_setDayTime(),style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 34),),
                        Text("Welcome back",style: getArimoRegular().copyWith(fontSize: 20),)
                      ],
                    )),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        Get.toNamed(Utils.cartRoute);
                      },
                      child : Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                            color: Colors.grey.shade200
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart,size: 20,),),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Gap(10),
                    Center(
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 20,
                        foregroundImage: NetworkImage(userImage),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/banner.png",fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 200,width: double.maxFinite,),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25,right: 20,top: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(flex: 2,child: Text("Choose Category",style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 25),),),
                    Expanded(child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        Get.toNamed(Utils.viewAllRoute);
                      },
                      child: Text("View All",style: getArimoRegular().copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 130,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _titles.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedCategory = index;
                            });
                            BlocProvider.of<FurnitureBloc>(context).add(GetFurnitureEvent(_titles[index]));
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 70,
                                height: 70,
                                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                                  color: selectedCategory == index ? Colors.black : Colors.grey.shade200,
                                ),
                                child: Center(child: Image.asset(_images[index],filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                                  width: 40,height: 40,color: Colors.grey.shade500,),),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                              Center(child: Text(_titles[index],style: getArimoRegular().copyWith(fontSize: 16),),)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15),
                child: BlocBuilder<FurnitureBloc,ShopBlocState>(
                  builder: (context,state){
                    if(state is LOADING){
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    }
                    else if (state is ERROR){
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(state.e.toString(),style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 20),),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    else if(state is GetFurnitureState){
                      var data = state.furniture;
                      if(data.isNotEmpty){
                        return GridView.builder(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: data.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                            childAspectRatio: 0.8, // Adjust the aspect ratio to ensure cards are not too tall
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                    child:  ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                        imageUrl : data[index]!.image!,
                                        placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset("assets/images/no_image.png"),
                                        width : double.maxFinite,
                                        height: 180,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                                        fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                            child:  Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  data[index]!.title!,
                                                  style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 15),
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                  "${data[index]!.price}\$",
                                                  style: getArimoRegular().copyWith(fontSize: 15),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )),
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 40,
                                            height: 40,
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                StorageHelper.setPosition(0);
                                                Get.toNamed(Utils.detailsRoute,arguments:data[index]?.id!);
                                              },
                                              child: Card(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                                ),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/images/arrow.png",
                                                    width: 15,
                                                    height: 15,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                      else {
                        return SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("No Furniture Found",style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 20),),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("No Furniture Found",style: getArimoBold().copyWith(fontSize: 20),),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),);
  }
  String _setDayTime(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("hh a");
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    String formattedString = dateFormat.format(dateTime);
    if(formattedString.contains("AM")){
      return "Good Morning";
    } else {
      return "Good Evening";
    }
  }

}


read Bloc.on documentation - it has an optional transformer parameter that defines how events are transformed - this part of documentation states what you can do with the transformer: "By default, events will be processed concurrently.
See also:
EventTransformer to customize how events are processed.
package:bloc_concurrency for an opinionated set of event transformers.
"

It depends on how you have declared events consumption inside constructor of Bloc. If you are using same 'on', events will be consumed one after another but if you have different 'on', they should arrive in parallel.
Sample code
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _stopwatch.start();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => MyBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<MyBloc>().add(const FirstEvent());
    context.read<MyBloc>().add(const SecondEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(builder: (context, state) {
          return switch (state) {
            Uninitialized() => const Text('Uninitialized'),
            Loading() => const Text('Loading'),
            Loaded() => Text(state.data),
            Failed() => Text(state.error),
          };
        }, listener: (context, state) {
          String msg = state.toString();
          printMsg(msg);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void printMsg(String msg) {
  print('${_stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds}ms: $msg ');
}

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() : super(const Uninitialized()) {
    on<FirstEvent>((event, emit) async {
      printMsg('processing first event');
      emit(const Loading());
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      emit(const Loaded('First data'));
    });

    on<SecondEvent>((event, emit) async {
      printMsg('processing second event');
      emit(const Loading());
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
      emit(const Loaded('Second data'));
    });
  }
}

@immutable
sealed class MyEvent extends Equatable {
  const MyEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class FirstEvent extends MyEvent {
  const FirstEvent();
}

class SecondEvent extends MyEvent {
  const SecondEvent();
}

sealed class MyState extends Equatable {
  const MyState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  @override
  bool? get stringify => true;
}

class Uninitialized extends MyState {
  const Uninitialized();
}

class Loading extends MyState {
  const Loading();
}

class Loaded extends MyState {
  final String data;
  const Loaded(this.data);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data];
}

class Failed extends MyState {
  final String error;
  const Failed(this.error);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}


dependencies used
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.6
meta: ^1.15.0
equatable: ^2.0.5

Sample output
126ms: processing first event
128ms: Loading()
128ms: processing second event
5136ms: Loaded(First data)
10138ms: Loaded(Second data)


read Bloc.on documentation - it has an optional transformer parameter that defines how events are transformed - this part of documentation states what you can do with the transformer: "By default, events will be processed concurrently.
See also:
EventTransformer to customize how events are processed.
package:bloc_concurrency for an opinionated set of event transformers.
"

@pskink the user want parallel processing. Hence I have not put any transformer. The user has not provided any bloc implementation hence I shared a sample with concurrent processing. Also, I am big fan of yours. :-)

First, I suggest to read about Dart Concurrency and Bloc Docs again, and then take look at this package  and more details about Bloc Transformers on this article
